# Cannot get reaction owner

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I wanted to make a command that sends a message when someone reacts on a message with their name, I can't make it get the name of the person that reacted.

```
if (reaction.emoji.name === firstEmoji) {
    await reaction.message.channel.send(`${reaction.message.author.username} reacted!`);
}
```

This will just say the bot's name and reacted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Firstly you should provide full code for an accurate answer***
Now, once the message is sent and if the bot is reacting to it before the user of course the bot would return itself.
Also for a better approach you can try using reaction collectors

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
};

const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    reaction.channel.send(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
});
```